# Height of <select> element in Bootstrap 4 different from other input elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Looking through the docs for Bootstrap 4, I came across this oddity:
http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#form-controls

Right now, in Chrome v48, the select element renders a lot smaller in height compared to other input elements.

In comparison, Bootstrap 3, doesn't have this problem:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#selects

Is this a conscious choice or due to it still being alpha?

Comment: just seems to be missing the padding. Probably not conscious choice, but it's still an alpha, so it remains to be seen. On a side-note, this question might be off-topic.

Comment: @Chris not the padding the height itself has that diff

Answer (score 0):

Yep on chrome select has a size of 20 while the other input fields are with a size of 24 (consider box model)

I don't know if this was a design choice or a fluke but on the style itself select is with a height of 34px and inputs with 38px.

If you want you can probably overwrite the style and get the desired behaviour.